# Python - Searching file lines for multiple patterns efficiently

Tags: python, file, search

I am working on parsing a number of large files and want to be sure I'm doing it as efficiently as possible. One of the lines I am parsing looks like this (a Windows Security Event Log 4624):

```
Security/Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing ID [4624] :EventData/Data -> SubjectUserSid = S-1-0-0 SubjectUserName = - SubjectDomainName = - SubjectLogonId = 0x0000000000000000 TargetUserSid = S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111 TargetUserName = johndoe TargetDomainName = TestDomain TargetLogonId = 0x0000000001111111 LogonType = 3 LogonProcessName = NtLmSsp  AuthenticationPackageName = NTLM WorkstationName = TestWorkstation LogonGuid = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} TransmittedServices = - LmPackageName = NTLM V2 KeyLength = 128 ProcessId = 0x0000000000000000 ProcessName = - IpAddress = 1.1.1.1 IpPort = 11111
```

What I want to know is, what is the most efficient way to pull multiple fields from that line? I could partition the line repeatedly until I reach each field I am interested in, but I feel like repeatedly looping over the line is a waste of time/resources.

Is there an intelligent way to look at the line only once but pull out, for example, the following fields:

```
LogonType = 3
TargetUserName = johndoe
TargetUserSid = S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111
```

As an example, what I could do is repeat the following process:

```
part = line.partition('TargetUserName = ')[2]
username = part.partition(' ')[0]
```

to get each field that I want (the above example getting me just the username), but again that feels inefficient to me.

Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: Have you looked at [regexes](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)?

Comment: Yeah I have used regex in the past, is there a way to match multiple patterns during the same regex operation? Or would I similarly have to have a different re.match() or search() for each pattern I'm interested in. Thanks!

Comment: Look at [the `.group()` method on regex matches](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each field name is a group of uppercase and lowercase characters. They are separated from their values by `=`. Each value is a group of non-whitespace characters. You can use `re.findall` with matching groups to locate all "letters = nonwhitespace" instances. This will give you a `list` of `tuple`s, which you can either save or iterate through and pass to a format string:

```
>>> s = '''Security/Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing ID [4624] :EventData/Data -> SubjectUserSid = S-1-0-0 SubjectUserName = - SubjectDomainName = - SubjectLogonId = 0x0000000000000000 TargetUserSid = S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111 TargetUserName = johndoe TargetDomainName = TestDomain TargetLogonId = 0x0000000001111111 LogonType = 3 LogonProcessName = NtLmSsp  AuthenticationPackageName = NTLM WorkstationName = TestWorkstation LogonGuid = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} TransmittedServices = - LmPackageName = NTLM V2 KeyLength = 128 ProcessId = 0x0000000000000000 ProcessName = - IpAddress = 1.1.1.1 IpPort = 11111 '''
>>> import re
>>> for item in re.findall(r'([A-Za-z]+) = (\S+)', s):
...     print('{} = {}'.format(*item))
...
SubjectUserSid = S-1-0-0
SubjectUserName = -
SubjectDomainName = -
SubjectLogonId = 0x0000000000000000
TargetUserSid = S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111
TargetUserName = johndoe
TargetDomainName = TestDomain
TargetLogonId = 0x0000000001111111
LogonType = 3
LogonProcessName = NtLmSsp
AuthenticationPackageName = NTLM
WorkstationName = TestWorkstation
LogonGuid = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
TransmittedServices = -
LmPackageName = NTLM
KeyLength = 128
ProcessId = 0x0000000000000000
ProcessName = -
IpAddress = 1.1.1.1
IpPort = 11111
```

You can also turn it into a dictionary for easy access:

```
>>> d = dict(re.findall(r'([A-Za-z]+) = (\S+)', s))
>>> d['LogonType']
'3'
```

Comment: This is awesome. One question - Is there a way I can do this same thing, but apply the .group() logic to it to only grab me the 'nonwhitespace' after the '=' ? Thanks!

Comment: If you've turned it into a dictionary (which I would recommend), you can get its values with `d.values()`.

Comment: But if you really don't want to capture the field names at all, you can simply remove the parentheses from around `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

```
    st = 'Security/Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing ID [4624] :EventData/Data -> SubjectUserSid = S-1-0-0 SubjectUserName = - SubjectDomainName = - SubjectLogonId = 0x0000000000000000 TargetUserSid = S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111 TargetUserName = johndoe TargetDomainName = TestDomain TargetLogonId = 0x0000000001111111 LogonType = 3 LogonProcessName = NtLmSsp  AuthenticationPackageName = NTLM WorkstationName = TestWorkstation LogonGuid = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} TransmittedServices = - LmPackageName = NTLM V2 KeyLength = 128 ProcessId = 0x0000000000000000 ProcessName = - IpAddress = 1.1.1.1 IpPort = 11111';

using re module and re.findall you can I think get want you want

    import re
    li = re.findall(r'LogonType\s*=\s*\d+|TargetUserName\s*=\s*\w+|TargetUserSid\s*=\s*\w-.*?\s',st,re.MULTILINE| re.DOTALL)
    >>>li
    ['TargetUserSid = S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111 ', 'TargetUserName = johndoe', 'LogonType = 3']
```